# Как зафиксировать кнопку на определенной высоте в bootstrap внутри div

Tags: bootstrap

Это примерный код bootstrap с кнопкой. У меня есть алгоритм когда на карточке отключается изображение и(или) текст. Когда их нет, кнопка сдвигается вверх. Как можно кнопку зафиксировать не просто внизу, а на определенной высоте относительно card-lg штатными средствами bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card card-lg text-center">
    <img src="images/img.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Рисунок">
    <p>Здесь будет текст</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Кнопка</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы что собрались верстать чисто на классах bootstrap? У вас не получится.

Comment: Да. То то в документах ничего похожего не нашел. Самому надо писать css.? Изучим и напишем!)

Comment: Вот только написал для ещё одного, которому нужно было фиксировать кнопку внизу блока - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491959/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83/1491969#1491969